# Why the output of this c++ program is 3

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int i;

class A
{
public:
    ~A()
    {
        i=10;
    }
};

int foo()
{
    i=3;
    A ob;
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "i = " << foo() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is  3, why not 10.

Comment: You are setting i to 10 only in destructor. So the object ob is still valid when you print the value of i.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because destructors are conceptually run at block exit.

So  `ob` is constructed in the middle of `foo` but is destructed when returning from `foo`

Answer (score 6):

When you initialize a destructor, in your case, the object's destructor is called just before it is destroyed, that is, just before foo's execution completes. Since i becomes equal to 3 in the call to foo() you get 3. It would be equal to 10 only **after ** the destructor is called.
If you do this, you can probably observe  destructor's behaviour and understand:

```
class A
{
    public:
    ~A()
    {
        i=10;
         cout << "In destructor function, i = " << i<< endl;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You set the value `i = 10` in the destructor. And destructor get called in the block exit.

So in your code, after `return i;` in `foo()`, when the block exits, the value of i is getting set to 10.

In the `cout` statement, you are not printing the value of `i`, rather the return value of function `foo()`, so its giving 3;

```
cout << "i = " << foo() << endl;  // gives result 3
cout << "i = " << i << endl;      // gives result 10
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting

**i to 10
 only in destructor**. So the object **ob** is still valid when you print the value of i which is returned from the function before the object is destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

Once you return i's current value, it no longer is affiliated with the global variable, it's just a copy that has the value of i upon return. The destructor can then change whatever it likes, the copied value is frozen

Answer (score 2):

```
int foo()
{
    i=3;
    A ob;
    return i;
}
```

The `return` statement is encountered before we reach the `}`
The `return` value is already estimated before  calling the destructor which sets the variable value to `10`

Answer (score -3):

`~A()`

If it is without `~` i will be `i=10`